# Rotating a hitbox and detect that rotation in a calculation

Tags: java, lwjgl

I am making a 3D Java game but i have got problems when rotating a hitbox. I, upon this point, only used a method which detects if a Vector3f is in a box.

But in my game I want to rotate houses, for example, so that method won't work. I could use circulair hitboxes but that wouldn't work for every instance of objects.

So far i have used this simple calculation to detect if a location is in a hitbox.

```
    public boolean isinbox(Vector3f pos) {
    Vector3f entPos = ent.getPosition();

    float x1 = entPos.x + xOffset;
    float z1 = entPos.z + zOffset;
    float y1 = entPos.y + yOffset;

    float x2 = entPos.x - xOffset;
    float z2 = entPos.z - zOffset;
    float y2 = entPos.y;

    return pos.x < x1 && pos.x > x2 && pos.z < z1 && pos.z > z2 && pos.y > y2 && pos.y < y1;
}
```

This works in many ways, but I can't figure out how to rotate them and still be able to detect it. The xOffset is the ofset if side a to the center and negative side b to the center.

How would I be able to rotate a hitbox and detect if an Vector is in it?

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of ways of getting around this issue and one (or more) ways of solving this issue:

## Solving It

### SAT Collision

SAT Stands for Separating Axis Theorem.
[TutsPlus](https://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/collision-detection-using-the-separating-axis-theorem--gamedev-169) and [MetaSoftware](http://www.metanetsoftware.com/technique/tutorialA.html) are great websites to learn how it works and how to implement it.

> The Separating Axis Theorem (SAT for short) essentially states if you are able to draw a line to separate two polygons, then they do not collide. It's that simple. (gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com)

Here is the basic idea:

[image]

It can also be used for more complex shapes:
[image]

## Getting Around It

### AABB Collision

This is done by assuming that collisions will only ever happen on the X/Y axis (never on an axis defined by an arbitrary line).
Here is an example of what this looks like:
[image]
Therefore, you must define this axis-aligned hitbox by using the minimum X-and-Y values and the maximum X-and-Y values of the original box.

### Circle Collision

This is a much simpler collision check which only detects when two objects are within a certain distance of each other.
Here is an example of what this looks like:
[image]
The way this works is that if the distance between the two objects is less than the sum of each circle's radius, then the objects are colliding.

### Using an External Library

- [Bullet Physics](http://bulletphysics.org/wordpress/)
- [Box2D](http://box2d.org/)